# VLC doesn't skip gaps during HLS transcoding

Tags: vlc, http-live-streaming, transcoding

I want to stream over HLS ASF file with H264 stream. I'm using VLC for transcoding to .ts files and creating index. Command looks like that:

vlc.exe test.asf --sout=#duplicate{dst=std{access=livehttp{seglen=2,delsegs=true,numsegs=2, index=mystream.m3u8,index-url=mystream-####.ts},mux=ts{use-key-frames},dst=mystream-####.ts}}

VLC creates ts files and refreshes index, IIS publishes the stream and everything goes fine. But if there is a gap in file, for example there is no samples with timestamps from 10 to 20 sec, VLC will wait for 10 sec and after that continue streaming which is no suitable for me.
Is it possible somehow tell vlc to skip gaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't found anything but recalculating timestamps before feeding video to VLC.